# Platform Encryption - Encryption at Rest

Tags: platform-encryption

I have enabled platform encryption at my DE and selected Case **Subject**, **Description** and **Comments** to be encrypted.

I have a created a sample case with these values:

[image: case]

And when I query from Developer Console it returns as follows:

[image: Case query]

> How do I know, subject and description are encrypted at Rest? Is there any indicator which can confirm that this data is encrypted?

*By the way, in case of File/attachment there is `isEncrypted` attribute is available which denotes the same as follows*.

[image: attachment]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I describe the field from Workbench, it denotes field is encrypted.

[image]

Since I am an authorized user to access this record that's why I can read the data in a normal way.

To make it full proof, I have archived the previous key:

[image: key management]

Then, destroy the previous key based on which data got generated.

[image: destroy tenant secret]

Now, access the same case record, it is showing `?????` (This service is unavailable right now.). This means encrypted data which has been encrypted with my previous tenant key is not available.

[image: Case subject encryption]

Then, I import the same existing key as follows:

[image: Import]

After, importing access the same case record, it is showing as follows:

[image: description]

**So, it is evident, Salesforce platform encryption encrypts at Rest.**

Comment: nice proof ....